# Querying using query parameters in Postman

Tags: api, postman

As a beginner to Postman, I am trying to use Query Parameters to search via filtering by keys. COnsider the following content of a certain endpoint.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "The Russian",
        "type": "fiction",
        "available": true
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Just as I Am",
        "type": "non-fiction",
        "available": false
    }
]
```

**1st scenario :**
Doing a GET on the endpoint with the syntax `{{baseURL}}/books?type=fiction`, I get

```
[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "The Russian",
            "type": "fiction",
            "available": true
        }
]
```

which is correct.

**2nd scenario :**
Doing a GET on the endpoint with the syntax `{{baseURL}}/books?id=1`, I get

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "The Russian",
        "type": "fiction",
        "available": true
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Just as I Am",
        "type": "non-fiction",
        "available": false
    }
]
```

which is not filtering by id = 1. It display id = 2 item as well. I was expecting it to show item base on id = 1 only.

AM I missing anything in understanding on how to use the query parameters ?

Comment: It depends on back-end code, client (FE) cannot define filters.

Comment: Thanks @lucas-nguyen-17 ! Does that mean I need to check with the dev on which key they allow for filtering ?

Comment: Yes, definitely. Tester'd better review API docs before reaching out developers.